# Usage of string parameter in "execute shell command" section of Jenkins

Tags: java, shell, deployment, jenkins, jobs

I have a string parameter configured for a jenkin job named "Job_Name".

I want to check the value that is passed to the parameter in "execute shell command" section of jenkins.

My current shell command is as below in the given pic.

[image]

Shell command:

```
if [ "${Job_Name}" == "RSProductPreprocessor" ]; then
ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook  -i hosts/dev playbook_deployRSProductPreProcessor.yml -v --extra-vars "RSProductPreProcessorVersion=${Number_Of_RSProductPreProcessor_Build_To_Deploy}"
fi
```

But I am getting this response as below when I run the job.

```
+ '[' '' == RSProductPreprocessor ']'
Finished: SUCCESS
```

What should be done for the if condition to work properly. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of things to fix

Click the link under your shell to see available environment variables

This is some of mine

```
BUILD_NUMBER
The current build number, such as "153"
BUILD_ID
The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss)
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME
The display name of the current build, which is something like "#153" by default.
JOB_NAME
Name of the project of this build, such as "foo" or "foo/bar". (To strip off folder paths from a Bourne shell script, try: ${JOB_NAME##*/})
```

So you need `${JOB_NAME}` all in capitals

And a comparison in shell is

```
if [ "${JOB_NAME}"="xxxx" ]; then
    ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook  -i hosts/dev playbook_deployRSProductPreProcessor.yml -v --extra-vars "RSProductPreProcessorVersion=${Number_Of_RSProductPreProcessor_Build_To_Deploy}"
fi
```

So only a single `=`

Your Jenkins may be using a different shell to mine so you can force bash by adding a shebang to the first line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

`$JOB_NAME` is a Jenkins generated variable. It cannot be overwritten.

You cannot have a string parameter called `$Job_Name`. Give it a different name, one that isn't reserved by Jenkins.